# How to run and stop an application at certain time on Heroku?

Tags: python, heroku-cli

I have an application on Heroku and it is written in python. But, I heard that the free version of Heroku only give us 550 hours so I want to save a little of it.

Is there any way to stop an application at a certain time and rerun it at a certain time on Heroku?

Comment: The free version already does saves dyno hours automatically by going to sleep when your application is idle. Does that satisfy your needs? Alternatively, by confirming your account with a credit card you get enough free hours to run constantly.

Answer (score 0):

This is not possible via the Heroku API, the only way you could achieve this is using the Heroku CLI and running the `heroku ps` command and somehow parsing the response:

```
heroku ps -a <app name>

650 free dyno hours (65%) used
350 hours remaining

=== web (Free): bundle exec puma -C config/puma.rb (1)
web.1: idle 2016/05/16 15:51:45 -0700 (~ 22h ago)
```

Reference: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/free-dyno-hours#determining-your-free-dyno-hours

Ideally, you could just track the total runtime of your application yourself and use that to determine when it should be stopped.